# Using a Regex to find specifically formatted fields

Tags: c#, .net, regex

In an application I'm developing, someone thought it would be ok idea to include commas in the values of a csv file.  So what I'm trying to do select these values and then strip the commas out of these values.  But the Regex I've built won't match to anything.

***The Regex pattern is:*** `.*,\"<money>(.+,.+)\",?.*`

And the sort of values I'm trying to match would be the `2700, 2650 and 2600 in  "2,700","2,650","2,600"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the answer Ryan. I should've kept my temper in check a bit more. Though still, commas in a CSV that don't seperate values?

After asking around the office I got pointed towards a free Regex designer application that I used to build the pattern I needed. The application is [Rad Software Regular Expression Designer](http://www.radsoftware.com.au/regexdesigner/)

Oh and for the answer purposes the pattern I came out with is: 
`\"(?<money>[0-9,.$]*)\"`

**Edit: Final Andwer**

Woah. Completely forgot about this question. I played around with the regex even more and came out with one that would match everything I needed. The regex is:

`\"([0-9.$]+(,[0-9.]+)+)\"`

That regex has been able to match any deciaml string within a double quote that I've thrown at it.

Answer (score 2):

Commas are allowed in CSV's and should not cause a problem if you use a text qualifier (usually double quote ").

Here are details: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values

**On to the regex:**

This code works for your sample data (but only allows one comma, basically thousands seperated numbers up to 999,999):

```
string ResultString = null;
try {
    ResultString = Regex.Replace(myString, "([0-9]{1,3})(?:(,)?([0-9]{3})?)", "$1$3");
} catch (ArgumentException ex) {
    // Syntax error in the regular expression
}
```

It takes this:

> Test 12,205   26,000 Test. And the sort
>   of values I'm trying to match would be
>   the 2700, 2650 and 2600 in
>   "2,700","2,650","2,600"

and produces this:

> Test 12205   26000 Test. And the sort
>   of values I'm trying to match would be
>   the 2700 2650 and 2600 in
>   "2700","2650","2600"